# RSA Encrypt string with given public key XML - modules and exponent - ANDROID

Tags: android, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement the login logic in my android app.

This is the scenario:

- on click the app send a GET Request to Azure Server and receive an XML string with the RSA Public Key (module + exp)
- the password is hashed and encripted
- RSA(hash(pwd)) is sent to my server.

I'm using this logic in my angular app and it working well.

**The problem**

When I'm trying to encrypt my hashed password the method retur some illeggible character.. A conversion problem?

**The Android Code**

```
    if (jsonToken.has("data"))
    {
        // Converte la Stringa in XML
        String publicToken = jsonToken.getString("data");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document publicTokenXML = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(publicToken)));


        Log.i("out", token.toString());
        Log.i("outXML", publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent());

        // prendo le due parti che mi servono dall'XML
        byte[] expBytes = Base64.decode(publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
        byte[] modBytes = Base64.decode(publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getTextContent(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
        byte[] dBytes = Base64.decode(d, Base64.DEFAULT);


        BigInteger modules = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");


        RSAPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modules, exponent);
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(bin2hex(getHash(pwd)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        // new String(encrypted)) is correct?!?
        Log.i("encrypted: ", new String(encrypted));

        RSAPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modules, d);
        PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(decrypted));
        Log.i("hash", bin2hex(getHash(pwd)));
    }
```

'decrypted' and 'hash' logs return to me the same hash string. I logged the part of the public and private key and they are correct.

**BUT**

[image: The android studio output]

How I can read it in the right form?

Thanks everyone.

** ***EDIT/Solution*** **

For who, how me, followed some tutorial on the web for implement RSA encryption in .NET, this is the solution that worked for me for the scenario I described at the top of the SO Query:

**The Android Code**

```
    if (jsonToken.has("data"))
    {
        // Converte la Stringa in XML
        String publicToken = jsonToken.getString("data");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document publicTokenXML = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(publicToken)));


        Log.i("out", token.toString());
        Log.i("outXML", publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent());

        // <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>*Modulus*</Modulus><Exponent>*Exponent*</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
        byte[] expBytes = Base64.decode(publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] modBytes = Base64.decode(publicTokenXML.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getTextContent(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] dBytes = Base64.decode(d, Base64.DEFAULT);


        BigInteger modules = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        // *****
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        // *****

        RSAPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modules, exponent);
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(bin2hex(getHash(pwd)).getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // *****
        Log.i("encrypted: ", Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", ""));
        // *****

        // Decrypt
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modules, d);
        PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(decrypted));
        Log.i("hash", bin2hex(getHash(pwd)));
    }
```

** The .NET Core code **

```
    private string RsaMyAndroidDecrypt(string passwordCrypt)
    {

        // Don't use OAEP padding (PKCS#1 v2).
        var doOaepPadding = false;
        // ------------------------------------------------
        // Decrypt
        // ------------------------------------------------
        // Convert base64 string back to bytes.
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordCrypt);

        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        // Import the RSA Key information.
        rsa.ImportParameters(keyForUserPassword.ExportParameters(true));
        // Decrypt byte array.
        var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, doOaepPadding);
        // Get decrypted data.
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
```

Comment: You are printing the binary data to the log file this will never work. Never ever call `new String(encrypted)` on a `byte[]` that contains binary data! Convert it to hex or base64 before printing!

Comment: Do some research on character encodings. Note that not all byte values are encodable to printable characters.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. Instead, please [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you the most. (If you found the answer yourself, you can even [self answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.) If you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) any answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET core you shouldn't use RSACryptoServiceProvider, but rather:

```
private byte[] Decrypt(string input)
{
    // Don't use OAEP padding (PKCS#1 v2).
    RSAEncryptionPadding padding = RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1;

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Decrypt
    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Convert base64 string back to bytes.
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordCrypt);

    // Create a new instance of RSA.
    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
    {
        // Import the RSA Key information.
        rsa.ImportParameters(keyForUserPassword.ExportParameters(true));

        // Decrypt byte array.
        byte[] decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, padding);
        return decryptedBytes;
    }
}
```

I'm ignoring the part here where you're turning it into a UTF-8 string.  And the part where you're recovering a thing that you call a password.

RSACryptoServiceProvider only works on Windows.  RSA.Create() will return an appropriate implementation of RSA for whatever platform the code is executing on.